# Weird value of #function literal in Swift 3.1

Tags: swift, function

I found out that the `String` returned by `#function` literal in Swift 3.1 is... weird. Here:

```
class FunctionLiteralTest {
    func weirdo() -> String {
        return #function
    }

    func weirdo(parameter: Int) -> String {
        return #function
    }

    func weirdo(_ parameter: Int) -> String {
        return #function
    }

    func weirdo(_ parameter: Int, _ anotherParameter: Int) -> String {
        return #function
    }
}

let functionLiteralTest = FunctionLiteralTest()

functionLiteralTest.weirdo()             // returns "weirdo()"
functionLiteralTest.weirdo(parameter: 1) // returns "weirdo(parameter:)"
functionLiteralTest.weirdo(1)            // returns "weirdo"
functionLiteralTest.weirdo(1, 2)         // returns "weirdo"
```

Parentheses are skipped entirely when all parameters are unlabeled. I would quite understand that if `#function` returned function name without parentheses for functions without any parameters too.

Is that justified behavior or a bug?

Comment: Odd, i would have expected `weirdo()`, `weirdo(parameter:)`, `weirdo(_:)` and `weirdo(_:_:)`

Comment: Exactly! Or at least just `weirdo` for all of them, skipping parameters entirely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Swift 5 update

In Swift 5 (not officially released yet, but you can pick up a [master snapshot](https://swift.org/download/#snapshots)), this inconsistency is fixed thanks to [#19062](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/19062). Your code now outputs the following:

```
functionLiteralTest.weirdo()             // returns "weirdo()"
functionLiteralTest.weirdo(parameter: 1) // returns "weirdo(parameter:)"
functionLiteralTest.weirdo(1)            // returns "weirdo(_:)"
functionLiteralTest.weirdo(1, 2)         // returns "weirdo(_:_:)"
```

---

#### Pre Swift 5

I agree this is completely baffling behaviour, but it does *appear* to be intentional.

Function literals get "filled in" in the process of SILGen; and this is done through the [`SILGenFunction::emitLiteral`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/80b180a/lib/SILGen/SILGenApply.cpp#L4680) function in [SILGenApply.cpp](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/SILGen/SILGenApply.cpp).

This then calls onto [`getMagicFunctionString`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/80b180a/lib/SILGen/SILGenApply.cpp#L4559) for a function literal:

> ```
> static StringRef
> getMagicFunctionString(SILGenFunction &SGF) {
>   assert(SGF.MagicFunctionName
>          && "asking for #function but we don't have a function name?!");
>   if (SGF.MagicFunctionString.empty()) {
>     llvm::raw_string_ostream os(SGF.MagicFunctionString);
>     SGF.MagicFunctionName.printPretty(os);
>   }
>   return SGF.MagicFunctionString;
> }
> ```

Which, if not already generated, creates a new stream to output to `MagicFunctionString`, and calls [`DeclName::printPretty`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/f8c2692/lib/AST/Identifier.cpp#L158) on `MagicFunctionName` with this stream:

> ```
> llvm::raw_ostream &DeclName::printPretty(llvm::raw_ostream &os) const {
>   return print(os, /*skipEmptyArgumentNames=*/true);
> }
> ```

(`MagicFunctionName` is assigned [when the function is emitted](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7f22faf/lib/SILGen/SILGenFunction.cpp#L383); and [is given the value of](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7f22faf/lib/SILGen/SILGenFunction.cpp#L75) `getFullName()`, which [is just the `Name`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/f117795/include/swift/AST/Decl.h#L2128) of the declaration)

This then calls onto [`DeclName::print`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/f8c2692/lib/AST/Identifier.cpp#L122), which as its second parameter takes a boolean argument to determine whether to skip listing argument names if they're all empty:

> ```
> llvm::raw_ostream &DeclName::print(llvm::raw_ostream &os,
>                                    bool skipEmptyArgumentNames) const {
>   // Print the base name.
>   os << getBaseName();
>
>   // If this is a simple name, we're done.
>   if (isSimpleName())
>     return os;
>
>   if (skipEmptyArgumentNames) {
>     // If there is more than one argument yet none of them have names,
>     // we're done.
>     if (getArgumentNames().size() > 0) {
>       bool anyNonEmptyNames = false;
>       for (auto c : getArgumentNames()) {
>         if (!c.empty()) {
>           anyNonEmptyNames = true;
>           break;
>         }
>       }
>
>       if (!anyNonEmptyNames)
>         return os;
>     }
>   }
>
>   // Print the argument names.
>   os << "(";
>   for (auto c : getArgumentNames()) {
>     os << c << ':';
>   }
>   os << ")";
>   return os;
>
> }
> ```

And you can see that because of the if condition `if (getArgumentNames().size() > 0)`, functions with no parameters will skip the check for all empty argument names, leading them to being emitted *with* parentheses, e.g `weirdo()`. But functions with one or more parameters, all with empty argument names, get emitted without parenthesis, e.g `weirdo`.

So, given `DeclName::printPretty` specifically passes `true` for the `skipEmptyArgumentNames` argument, it seems that the Swift team do specifically want this behaviour for `#function`.

Furthermore, if we look at the blame, we can see that `DeclName::printPretty` was added in [this commit](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/3d4df3427aa5f38319a55486217e68052b7d8870), with the commit message:

> **Pretty-print DeclNames with no keyword arguments by dropping the
>   parenthsized bit.**
>
> Instead of printing "`f(_:_:)`", just print "`f`".

That being said, I would still [file a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/) over it, as it doesn't seem that intuitive for function literals.

Comment: @RoboRobok And now [this will be fixed](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/19062) in Swift 5 :)